# Unity Timeline Animation Event Not Firing

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, timeline

I've been trying to get to grips with the Timeline feature in Unity, but I am having problems where an animation event is not firing when I think it should.

I have an object that is animated by an animation track containing two animation clips. The first clip contains an animation event at the end. This clip is looped 7 times. The second clip is then played once:

[image]

I would expect to observe the event 7 times, but I only see it 6 times - the very last event does not fire.

If I add a gap between the two clips then all 7 events correctly fire:

[image]

The clips are short in duration - I think there is some sort of blending done by the timeline between the two clips that stops the last event firing. Ease In and Ease-out duration are set to 0. I've tried changing the extrapolation and Blend Curve settings, but nothing seems to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been confirmed as a bug in Unity - [fixed in 2019.1](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/timeline-sequence-doesnt-fire-animation-events-that-are-on-the-last-frames-when-several-clips-are-played).

Comment: I had this problem as well, running 2019.1.8f1 - I found another post about layer weight needing to be non-zero. I was using the animation event to trigger a coroutine that blended the layer weight from 0. By setting the layer weight to a small number instead of zero, the animation event fired.